# Как можно отфильтровать по первой букве строкового столбца?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, фильтрация, обработка-данных

У меня есть DataFrame `dat`, состоящий из нескольких столбцов, в том числе `OS` и `Type`. Нужно создать новый DataFrame (или отфильтровать исходный), чтобы в столбце `OS` (в нем перечислены разные операционные системы) была только "Windows", а в столбце `Type` - только архитектуры, название которых начинается на "i". Первую задачу я выполняю:

```
da = dat[dat.OS == 'Windows']
```

Вторую часть пытаюсь выполнить разными способами, но не получается. Например:

```
df = da[da.Type[0] == 'i']
```

Как можно отсортировать DataFrame по первой букве элементов столбца? Или как удалить все строки, у которых элементы столбца "Type" начинаются не с "i"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = da.loc[da.Type.str.startswith('i')]
```

В `Pandas` много перетянули функций для работы со строками из стандартного питона. Когда не знаете что искать, надо всегда сначала смотреть аналогичные функции. Которые, конечно, нужно ещё знать для этого.

А отсортировать вы можете просто по столбцу, сортировка пойдёт сначала по первой букве, потом по второй и т.д.

```
df = da.sort_values('Type')
```

Comment: Спасибо, просветили)

Comment: @AndrewTim, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Небольшое отступление - судя по деталям и по коду из вопроса, вопрос о том, как фильтровать данные, а не о сортировке (упорядочивание порядка записей, не меняя их количества).

Кроме варианта решения, предоставленного [@CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222332), можно использовать следующие варианты:

#### вариант 1

```
da.loc[da['Type'].str.match('i')]
```

#### вариант 2

```
da.loc[da['Type'].str.contains('^i')]
```

#### вариант 3

```
da.loc[da['Type'].str[0] == 'i']
```

#### вариант 4

```
da.loc[da['Type'].str[:1] == 'i']
```

#### вариант 5

```
da.loc[da['Type'].str.slice(0, 1) == 'i']
```

Comment: 1 и 3 варианты совпадают или у меня что-то с глазами? )

Comment: да, у меня мысли обгоняют руки при наборе ответов :-D